# Flutter: Creating re-usable widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

My application is based on forms, and it has a lot of Text Fields involved. All Fields are sharing same style, and form pages are becoming lengthy so I decided to create a `widget` and call it where needed.

I created a file `show_text_field.dart` with this code:

```
showTextField(String label, var variable){
return TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onSaved: (val) => variable = val,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),

      )),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return '$label cannot be empty';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
);
}
```

It works normally, but I'm unable to retrieve value from the field.

**Questions:**

1. How can I get value from `onSaved` event?
2. Is this correct approach?
3. Is it better to create re-usable `InputDecoration` widget, instead of reusing entire widget?
4. If it's correct approach then is there any way to extend/modify field validator?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you miss one, very important thing. If you want to retrieve the value outside of your component you have to pass it via showTextField function param. I would do it like that:

```
showTextField(String label, var variable, Function onSaved)
```

your end code can look like this:

```
showTextField(String label, var variable, Function onSaved){
return TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onSaved: onSaved,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),

      )),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return '$label cannot be empty';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
);
}
```

Thanks to that you would be able to implement the logic that you need when event `onSaved` is executed.

ad 2. All depends on your needs. If you need to handle the value on submit then it is good approach.

ad 3. Here also all depends. I would do it in the way you do it, but here also all depends on the context of the problem that it has to solve

ad 4. Wha do you mean by `extend/modify filed validation`? You have the `validator` where you can do whatever you want/need. You can also pass the Function to make custom validation for all fields in your form (I assume that you might want to validate different fields differently)

Comment: thanks for your answer, how do I pass `onSaved` function? Yes, you are right I wanted to validate fields differently so in that case, I've to modify validator. Can you please provide an example for that?

Comment: You can pass it while executing the showTextField like that: showTextField("label", variable, (value){ here you put the code})

Comment: I call it like this `showTextField( 'label', var, (val) => _test = val),` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try doing it like that:

`
showTextField('label', var, (val) {_test = val;})`

Comment: If this would not work I would use the `onChanged` method instead of `onSaved`. This one is called every time you type something into the input field. Because there might be a situation that you does not submit the value and the onSaved is not called

Comment: The `onSaved` doesn't work, however it worked with `onChanged`

Comment: I am glad I could help. About the `onSaved` event I think it will be fired when you use `Return` key to focus next input/form field. When you change the focus by tapping on the next field it might be skipped, but this is only my assumption and I have not checked it